# Running Linux as a switch, but switch not receiving ARP reply

Tags: linux, bridge, vlan

I am trying to get Linux to function as a switch by bridging two network interfaces together, but do not appear to get to ARP replies to flow back. My topology is as follows:

[Client 1] -- [Linux Switch] -- [Client 2]

The "switch" is basically two interfaces bridged together. The Clients share connections to the two ports on the Switch.

I ran them as follows:

`brctl addbr bridger
brctl addif enp0s3
brctl addif enp0s8
ifconfig bridger up`

When client 1 sends a ping, it initiates by sending a "who-has" request to the Linux "Switch". The Linux "Switch" sends that request to Client 2. A tcpdump(8) on Client 2 reveals that there is a "Reply to 10.1.0.1 is-at 08:00:27:69:da:47 (oui Unknown), length 28".

However, the Linux "switch" does not appear to receive that responses at all. Either the client is failing to send them (which does not appear to be the case due to the tcpdump line) or the switch is failing to receive them. What is causing this?

I have eliminated all iptables(8) rules as follows:

`iptables -t nat -F
iptables -F`

The hypervisor is virtualbox on Windows, all VMs are Ubuntu and I have disabled network-management everywhere.

Comment: Good question, it should "just work". Check that there are also no rules in the other tables `-t filter`, `-t mangle`, `-t raw`. Check that `ebtables` is not loaded, or no rules are active if it is loaded. Do `tcpdump` both on `enp0s3` and `enp0s8` (two windows), and see if the arp reply at least arrives. You can use `bridge` instead of `brctl` to inspect the forwarding database (`sudo bridge fdb show`), check if the MAC addresses of Client 1 and Client 2 are correct.

Comment: I have done all of the above, no dice. Odd.

Comment: Wild shot: Any network interfaces with an IP range overlapping that of Client 1 or Client 2?

Comment: if one VMs sends traffic and the other VM doesn't receive it, the problem is between both: the hypervisor. You'll have to check what filtering settings are set on the hypervisor. As it's Virtualbox on Windows, who knows...